# Is there a ways extract image from video by frame and join in later with auto remove duplicate pixel area?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, images, compression

Is there a ways to extract image from video. but its not just extract image frame by frame. but the extract image automatically optimize by removing duplicate area pixel by 1 second?

lets 1 second have 24 frames. its default cinema fps. what i want, it extract 24 frames with auto remove duplicate area and have information for later to me to decode it back.

the use case, we can take advantage free unlimited host image to reconstruct a video from big social media like facebook, twitter, and so on.

by default application like ffmpeg and so on. it extract a second frames, indenpendenly. its means a second frames. it will output 3.3MB in totall. or each frame or image 100-150KB.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It is kind of possible, but you are not going to know how to reconstruct the image. Assume the codec of the input file is h264, use `segment` muxer to split it into "frames": `ffmpeg -an -i tmp.mp4 -vcodec copy -f segment -segment_time 0.041666666666667 -break_non_keyframes 1 %07d.264`. For decoding a frame (getting the image), is going to be challenging. How do you intend to extract a frame when the frame depends on the previous frames?